# Date time Filed formate in my Asp.net grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am using this formate to display the date time in the grid. My problem is I am not getting the Exact HH:MM from the database. Database showing 11:11 but on my grid it showing 11:03..

```
Here is the database value : 2013-03-29 11:11:17.570

.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM  tt}")
```

Can Any body help me out why I am not getting this Exact HH:MM in my grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using month in place of minutes it should be small mm

Answer (score 1):

hello please use this format

"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm  tt}"